# Cambiar background de Navigation Drawer según en el fragmento que me encuentre

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment, android-drawerlayout, navigationview

soy nuevo en el desarrollo de aplicativos Android y quería saber como cambiar el background del Navegation Drawer según en el fragmento en el que me encuentre.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A que me refiero con esto? Que si me encuentro en el fragmento llamado Intelicard que la imagen de fondo de mi menú desplegable sea totalmente diferente a la que tendría por defecto mi fragmento inteligensa

```
package com.example.soporte.inteliapp2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, InteligensaFragment.OnfragmentInteractionListener, IntelCardFragment.OnfragmentInteractionListener, InteliTecFragment.OnfragmentInteractionListener, InteliFoneFragment.OnfragmentInteractionListener, InteliPuntoFragment.OnfragmentInteractionListener, InteliSoftFragment.OnfragmentInteractionListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        Fragment fragment= new InteligensaFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.contenedor,fragment).commit();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        Fragment myfragment = null;
        boolean fragmentSeleccionado = false;
        String tittle ="";


        if (id == R.id.nav_inteligensa) {
           myfragment = new InteligensaFragment();
           fragmentSeleccionado = true;
           tittle="INTELIGENSA";
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_intelicard) {
            myfragment = new IntelCardFragment();
            fragmentSeleccionado = true;
            tittle="INTELISEÑO";
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_intelitec) {
            myfragment = new InteliTecFragment();
            fragmentSeleccionado = true;
            tittle="INTELITEC";
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_intelifone) {
            myfragment = new InteliFoneFragment();
            fragmentSeleccionado = true;
            tittle="INTELIFONE";
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_intelipunto) {
            myfragment = new InteliPuntoFragment();
            fragmentSeleccionado = true;
            tittle="INTELIPUNTO";
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_intelisoft) {
            myfragment = new InteliSoftFragment();
            fragmentSeleccionado = true;
            tittle="INTELISOFT";
        }

        if(fragmentSeleccionado==true){
          getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor, myfragment).commit();
          getSupportActionBar().setTitle(tittle);

        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que puedes obtener de tu layout el `NavigationView` y hacer llamado en el caso que desees cambiar la imagen. i.e:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        Fragment myfragment = null;
        boolean fragmentSeleccionado = false;
        String tittle ="";


        if (id == R.id.nav_inteligensa) {
           myfragment = new InteligensaFragment();
           fragmentSeleccionado = true;
           tittle="INTELIGENSA";
          //realizas el cambio despues de haber obtenido el NavigationView 
        navigationView.setItemBackground(R.drawable.tu_background);
        } 


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: y como consigo el NavegationView?

Comment: Este debe estar en tu `main_layout` o el layout que estes usando en tu `onCreate` y lo obtienes de la misma manera que estas obteniendo tu `DrawerLayout` i.e: `NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view); `

Comment: Te recomiendo este sitio como guía a tus desarrollos para darte una idea mas clara, y como siempre esta la documentación de android en español. 

https://material.io/develop/android/components/navigation-view/